# Programming logic - Compare 3 values - JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

I have this snippet that is is getting 3 numbers and its working distinguing them. If one of 3 numbers is diferent than the others it must return its correspondend.

An input example:
1 1 0
0 0 0
1 0 0

output must be:
C
*
A

The approach i had was that one:

```js
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('stdin', 'utf8')
var lines = input.split('\n')

for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var round = lines[i].split(' ').map(i => parseInt(i))
  // console.log(round); [1, 1, 0]

  var A = round[0]
  var B = round[1]
  var C = round[2]

    if(A === B && A === C){
      console.log("*");
    } else if (A === B && A !== C) {
        console.log("C");
    } else if (A !== B && A === C) {
        console.log("B");
    } else if (A !== B && A !== C) {
        console.log("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: this is the entire problem description https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1467

Comment: OK, but what is your question? You've posted some code and described what it should do. If somebody was to write an answer, then what do they need to put in it?

Comment: perhaps a different approach on comparing the 3 values

Comment: One thing I can say is that you don't need the `!==` stuff: if you've already determined that they aren't all the exact same thing, then you just need the `else if (A === B)` and `else if (A === C)` and `else` (the last one can just be and else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is exactly but if it is to try to minimize the code in some way one thing to notice is that we don't care whether the the values are 0 or 1 only whether the players have chosen the same or not so once we have the values of A, B and C for a round we can just do:

(UPDATE: thanks to a comment from @Samathingamajig a redundant != comparison has been removed)

```
 console.log( ((A==B)&&(B==C)) ? '*' : (A==B) ? 'C' : (A==C) ? 'B' : 'A' );
```

Comment: If we're going for minimalism, you have redundant checks (the `!=`'s)

Comment: Thanks, Impressive spotting!. I've updated the answer.

Comment: There's also another 1 character fix by changing `&&` to `&` (yes, it works because bitwise true is 1, and bitwise false is 0, so it works), and also a lot of redundant parentheses, but this isn't [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The lack of parentheses around conditions in PHP is deprecated apparently (see e.g. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517474/php-deprecated-unparenthesized/64522419#64522419)  so I've taken to using them in JS too - ternary ops are hard enough to read as it is! I'm not so keen on putting single & - even though it might work in some particular situations. So I agree we could get rid of even more characters but I don't think I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Samathingamajig said:

```js
function _0or1(arr) {
    [A,B,C] = arr
    if (A === B && A === C) {
        console.log("*");
    } else if (A === B) {
        console.log("C");
    } else if (A === C) {
        console.log("B");
    } else {
        console.log("A");
    }
}

_0or1([0,0,0])
_0or1([1,0,0])
_0or1([0,1,0])
_0or1([0,0,1])
_0or1([1,1,0])
_0or1([0,1,1])
_0or1([1,0,1])
_0or1([1,1,1])
```