# PHP Deprecated: Unparenthesized

Tags: php

I found this debug error:  PHP Deprecated:  Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in /home/ptl4lmmge5kb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/give-recurring/includes/admin/class-subscriptions-list-table.php on line 143

The code from line 143 of the plugin shows this:

```
  ( ( 'all' === $key && empty( $current ) ) ) ? 'class="current"' : ( $current == $key ) ? 'class="current"' : '',
```

Can anyone tell me where to place the parenthesis?

Comment: It depends what your outcome is, parenthesis work the same way in programming as in maths, whatever is inside the parenthesis is evaluated first, then compared to the outside

Comment: `'all' === $key && empty($current) ? 'class="current"' : ($current == $key ? 'class="current"' : '')` too many uneeded ()'s and where they are needed not in the right place, btw its bad practice to nest ternerys for this reason

Comment: write like this instead: `'all' === $key && empty($current) || $current === $key ? 'class="current"' : ''`

Comment: Lawrence is right, though the path including `/wp-content/plugins/` worries me a bit. Is this code you wrote, or code in some sort of 3rd party wordpress plugin? If its the later, I wouldn't expect to edit that code directly but rather update the plugin that introduces that code.

Comment: No, I don't write code.  It is a third-party plugin called GiveWP - Recurring Donations.

Answer (score 0):

Taking their first request they are asking you to use a format like this `(a ? b : c) ? d : e`
in this

```
 ( ( 'all' === $key && empty( $current ) ) ) ? 'class="current"' : ( $current == $key ) ? 'class="current"' : ''
```

breaking it down into their terminaology in this case:

a is  `( 'all' === $key && empty( $current ) )` - there was an unneeded pair of brackets here, I've removed them as we've got enough problems sorting out brackets as it is

b is `'class="current"'`

c is ( $current == $key )

d is `'class="current"'`

e is `''`

what they are saying is that they want you to make it plain what is going to be tested for the second ? by putting the condition and result of the first in parentheses

The first is: (a ? b : c)

which becomes `( ( 'all' === $key && empty( $current ) ) ? 'class="current"' : ( $current == $key ) )`

So they ask that you use:

```
( ( 'all' === $key && empty( $current ) ) ? 'class="current"' : ( $current == $key ) ) ? 'class="current"' : ''
```